# Use dynamic service in component

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to use a component in two different modules, the component is using a service that has a certain state. the component also has child components that use the same service. I need two instances of the service because I don't want the actions in the component in module 1 to affect the state of the service in module two.
My current solution is that I inject the service in the component decorator and by that scope the service to the component instance. and I am passing this specific instance to the child components as `@input` field.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Share some code.

Comment: What is the purpose of having multiple instance of the same service? Do you store data in each Service?

Comment: Yes, I store data in each service

Comment: personally, I'll think in a solution based on Activated Router https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action to choose the service -you can simply equal a variable service to the different services in the subscribe- or passing data in router https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: edited my question with better explanation

Answer (score 1):

I would create an abstract class and extend it in components, you i would create new comps for every page.

```
export abstract class Base{
    constructor(protected service:any){}
}

export class Comp1 extends Base{
     constructor(protected service: Service1){
         super(service);
     }
}
export class Comp2 extends Base{
     constructor(protected service: Service2){
         super(service);
     }
}
```

This way you have to write your codes only once and it is very flexible to override anything in case you have to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you are looking for is a non-singleton service. Adding your service to the `providers` of your `app.module.ts` makes the service a singleton service, meaning only one instance of the service will be created which will live as long as your application does. You can instead add the service in the component making it a non-singleton service.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  providers: [SearchService]
})
```

This way when Angular destroys the component, it will also destroy the service. Non-singletons services also have the `ngOnDestroy()` lifecycle hook so make sure you unsubscribe your subscriptions to avoid any leakage of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions,

1. Services is not meant to store data.
2. Keep your service clean, sort and for common operations.
3. If you want different data based on different components, use some params to decide.

in your case you want different search result based on components, so you can create a common service which can take some params and fetch you result.

```
All the best
```